# How can I subclass Model and properly add a static method?

Tags: node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

I'm learning how to use Sequelize as the ORM for a small web app. Each record in the (MySQL) database has a `uuid` field. I want to add a `findByUuid` static method to all of the models. Here's my attempt:

```
class Base extends Model {
    static findByUuid = async (uuid) => {
        return await super.findOne({ where: {uuid: uuid} });
    }
}

class List extends Base {
}

List.init({
    uuid: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    nodelName: 'List',
    indexes: [
        { fields: ['name'] },
        { fields: ['uuid'] }
    ]
});

(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const list = List.build({name: 'New List'});
    await list.save();
    console.log('id: ' + list.id);
    console.log('uuid: ' + list.uuid);
    const direct_retrieved = await List.findOne({ where: {uuid: list.uuid} });
    console.log('direct name: ' + direct_retrieved.name);
    const retrieved = await List.findByUuid(list.uuid);
    console.log('static retrieved: ' + retrieved.name);
})();
```

And here's the output (excluding the echoed SQL commands):

```
id: 1
uuid: 371971dd-a4d9-43aa-ac10-afe3c10154b0
direct name: New List
/Users/chuck/Projects/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1692
    this.warnOnInvalidOptions(options, Object.keys(this.rawAttributes));
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at Function.findAll (/Users/chuck/Projects/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1692:47)
    at Function.findOne (/Users/chuck/Projects/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1917:23)
    at Function.findByUuid (/Users/chuck/Projects/app/models/models.js:7:36)
    at /Users/chuck/Projects/app/models/models.js:181:34
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
```

So directly working with `findOne` is working, but trying to do so within the static method causes the error, and I have not been able to figure out why.

I think the problem is that the `Base` class has no knowledge of a `uuid` field. If I put the static method into the `List` class, it works properly. So the only solution I have so far is to repeat that code for every actual table since I don't (yet) see a way to define the `uuid` field in the `Base` class (which would be preferable anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to override `init` to let `Base` know about the `uuid` field. Here's the working solution.

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = require('./helpers/sequelize');

class Base extends Model {
    static findByUuid = async (uuid) => {
        return await super.findOne({ where: {uuid: uuid} });
    }

    static init = (attributes, options = {}) => {
        attributes.uuid = {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
        };
        options.indexes.push({ fields: ['uuid'] });
        super.init(attributes, options);
    }
}

class List extends Base {
}

List.init({
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'List',
    indexes: [
        { fields: ['name'] }
    ]
});



(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    const list = List.build({name: 'New List'});
    await list.save();
    console.log('id: ' + list.id);
    console.log('uuid: ' + list.uuid);
    const direct_retrieved = await List.findOne({ where: {uuid: list.uuid} });
    console.log('direct: ' + direct_retrieved.name);
    const retrieved = await List.findByUuid(list.uuid);
    console.log('static: ' + retrieved.name);
})();
```